# Offset in cache Mips

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I know that offset is : block size=2^n (offset=n). But i have seen that when block size = 8 bytes we do : 8=2^n so offset=n=3 bits, which is correct, but when block size = 1 word, i have seen 1=2^n (offset=n=0). Dont we need to convert word to bytes if we know that cache has 32-bit memory address? (So we have 32bit=4bytes, 4=2^n offset is 2 in that case).

Comment: Units matters: a word is not a byte. So, yes, convert the unit "word" to the unit "byte".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your did right, It's intuitive that one should know that a `word` is 4 byte in 32 bit processor and 8 byte in 64 bit.

The `byte offset` can also can be find in this way, Assume you have address size 32 bits then
`byte_offset = 32-tag_bits-set_bits`.

In order to solve problem of this kind it's good to know some useful parameter and equation.

**Parameter to know**

```
C = cache capacity
b = block size
B = number of blocks
N = degree of associativity
S = number of set
tag_bits
set_bits (also called index)
byte_offset
v = valid bits
```

**Equations to know**

```
B = C/b
S = B/N
b = 2^(byte_offset)
S = 2^(set_bits)
```

**Memory Address**

```
|___tag________|____set___|___byte offset_|
```